# how to create a diamond in c using only 3 printf and 3 n\t\

Tags: c

I am attempting to create a diamond in c with the constraints of only 3 printfs and 3 n\t. this requires me to use loops. I know how to make an upside down triangle and a triangle but cant use that because there are too many printfs. i will attach my code so far. I am aware it does not make a diamond, and some awfully strange shape, but that it what i'm trying to work off and edit to make into a diamond, I just haven't been able to figure it out.

```
if (type_of_shape == 5)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
          for (j = 0;j < ((width - 1) / 2) - i ||(width -1)/2 < i && j + (width-1)/2 < i; j++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            for (k = 0;k<width && k < (j*2+1) ; k++)
            {   
                printf("*");
            }
                printf("\n");
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is `"n\t\"` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `"n\t\"` is a back-linefeed, back-tab combination. ;-)

Comment: @chux Thanks. I didn't know it. But they are not included in C, right?

Comment: I believe @chux is thinking of `"\n\t"`.  But the backslash (the escape character) must **precede** the letter, not follow it.

Answer (score 1):

```
//int width = 5;
int row, col;
int spaces, stars;
int half, rate;

half = width / 2 + 1;
rate = 1;

for(row = 1; 0 < row && row <= half; row += rate) {
    spaces = half - row;
    stars = row * 2 -1;
    printf("%*s", spaces, "");
    for (col = 0; col < stars; col++)
        printf("*");
    printf("\n");
    if(row == half)
        rate = -rate;
}
```

Comment: @sarah Did you see a demo? Can you see what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I got it down to a single line which has a single loop, with a single `printf` statement.

It involved some tricky use of `abs`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int w = 9;
    for(int l=0; l < w; ++l) printf("%*.*s\n", abs(w/2 - l)+abs((2*l+1)-(2*l+1>w)*2*w), abs((2*l+1)-(2*l+1>w)*2*w), "**************");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- 2 loops (one `for`, one `while`).
- 2 `printf` statements.

***Note:***
This works with odd Widths.
An even width produces a diamond with Width+1

My **[IDEOne code](http://ideone.com/FlLti9)**

```
int main(void)
{
    int width = 9;
    int layer;

    width+=2;
    for(layer=0; layer<width/2; ++layer)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n", width/2+layer + 1,layer*2 + 1, "**************************");
    }
    layer--;
    while (layer --> 0)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n", width/2+layer + 1,layer*2 + 1, "**************************");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

***Output***

```
Success time: 0 memory: 2168 signal:0
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```

Comment: is there anything i can replace the string of "******" with to make it cleaner? I know the diamond is made up of the * but Im just wondering if there is any other way to state that?

Comment: otherwise this was extremely helpful.

Comment: @sarah `char stars[width+1]; memset(stars, '*', width); stars[width] = 0;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY:  You should not need to null-terminate the string, since the intention is to for it to be more stars than are needed, and `printf` will always stop before the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with no loops at all. *(looping accomplished via recursion)*, and 3 `printf` statements:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void drawDiamond(int width, int stars)
{
    static const char* txt = "*****************************";
     if (stars == width)    {
        printf("%*.*s\n",width, width, txt);
        return;
    }

    printf("%*.*s\n", (width+stars)/2, stars, txt);
    drawDiamond(width, stars+2);
    printf("%*.*s\n", (width+stars)/2, stars, txt);
}

int main(void)
{
    drawDiamond(9, 1);
    return 0;
}
```